# mapbox: disable one feature rendering

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

i want to disable rendering of only one extruded building in my case, i looking for something like this

```
map.on('load', function () {
    map.addLayer({
        'id': '3d-buildings',
        'source': 'mapbox',
        'source-layer': 'building',
        "filter": ["!=", "id", "12345"],
        'type': 'fill-extrusion',
        'paint': {
            'fill-extrusion-color': '#bbb',
            'fill-extrusion-height': 10,
            'fill-extrusion-base': 0,
            'fill-extrusion-opacity': 1
        }
    });

})
```

following expression is incorrect:

```
"filter": ["!=", "id", "12345"]
```

**mapbox-gl-0.44.1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter retrieves the property value from the properties of the current feature. Make sure that the building id is in the properties:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "id": "12345",
    "base_height": 30,
    "height": 40
  },
  "geometry": {...}
  }
}
```

**Upd**: [Gets the feature's id, if it has one](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-id): `["id"]`. And, of course, you need to take into account the possible type of identifier:

```
"filter": ["!=", ["id"], 12345]
```

For example click on the building to hide it: [ https://jsfiddle.net/yedg641a/ ]

Comment: No, it is a open street map data buildings, and it has no id in properties

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Yes you are right. See addition to the answer.

Comment: @stdob-- Hi, I want to hide specific building with id: 619244114. however still not work.  `filter: ['all', ['>', 'height', 18], ['!=', 'id', 619244114]].`